# in the given function decrypt i want to pass content of a file geek.txt in place of encryptedText as argument

Tags: function, arguments, file-handling

i want to replace the encryptedText with content of a file geek.txt. The file contains 3 words in 3 different lines.how should i pass one of these words to this function as argument

```
 {
    public static String decrypt(String encryptedText, SecretKey secretKey)//how should i replace the encryptedText argument with some content of a file geek.txt
    throws Exception {
                                Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
                                byte[] encryptedTextByte = decoder.decode(encryptedText);
                                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
                                byte[] decryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(encryptedTextByte);
                                String decryptedText = new String(decryptedByte);
                                return decryptedText;
                     }
```

}